# How to fix Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error

Tags: python, django, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

After changing the url of my website from example1.com to example2.com I got the error of JSONDecodeError Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Moreover, thinking that may the woocommerce key and secret caused the problem I changed them also, but the problem remains.

Here is my code:

```
def create_woocommerce_products_individually(wcapi,name,code,regular_price):

        data = {
                "name": name,    
                "sku": code,
                "regular_price": str(regular_price),
                }
        wcapi.post("products", data).json()



class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name='products/product_create_form.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProductForm(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                self.object = form.save(commit=False)
                name=self.object.description
                code=self.object.code
                wholesale_status=self.object.wholesale_status
                regular_price=self.object.retail_price
                wcapi=get_wcapi_b2b()
                create_woocommerce_products_individually(wcapi,name,code,regular_price)
                r=wcapi.get("products?filter[sku]='"+code+"'").json()
                post_id=r[0]['id']
                self.object.pid=post_id
                self.object.save()


            else:
                form = ProductForm() 
        return super(ProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My aim is to create a Product both in my db and woocommerce api, that's why I call the `create_woocommerce_products_individually` function.

**How can I fix this error and save properly?**

Here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py" in dispatch
  56.         return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  217.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/var/www/vhosts/intranet.rodkok.gr/apografi/intranet/views.py" in form_valid
  330.                 create_woocommerce_products_individually(wcapi,name,code,regular_price)

File "/var/www/vhosts/intranet.rodkok.gr/apografi/intranet/views.py" in create_woocommerce_products_individually
  301.         wcapi.post("products", data).json()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py" in json
  892.         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py" in loads
  517.         return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py" in decode
  370.         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py" in raw_decode
  400.         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/scanner.py" in scan_once
  79.             return _scan_once(string, idx)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/scanner.py" in _scan_once
  70.             raise JSONDecodeError(errmsg, string, idx)

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /products/new/
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, I had to refresh the .htaccess file on my website